# How to bind SP.PermissionKind Enumeration to a dropdown list using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, jquery

I need help as I have a requirement to get all permissions (PermissionKind Enumeration)and bind it to a drop-down. Also, I need help to know what are the different ways to bind Enumerator value using jquery.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question... but as these are unchanged since SP 2007, why not just hand enter them into your HTML and use friendly names that your users may understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following code to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getPermissionKinds, "sp.js");
function getPermissionKinds() {  
    $.each(SP.PermissionKind, function(key, value) {
        if($.isNumeric(value)){
            $("#PermissionKinds").append("<option value="+value+">"+key+"</option>");
        }       
    }); 
}
</script>
<select id="PermissionKinds"></select>
```

[image]